# How do you declare a new public variable only if the previous has been used (C#)?

Tags: c#, variables, global-variables

I'm trying to add a new public variable only if the previous variable has been used. For example:

```
public bool Toggle;
private int Toggles;

void Update ()
{
   if (Toggle = ! null) 
   {
       public bool (Toggle + Toggles);
       Toggles = (Toggles+1);
   }
}
```

Theres a lot of things wrong with that. For one I can't declare a public variable inside and that would continuously add new strings.

edit: this is a terrible question i'm not sure what was going through my mind

Comment: This doesn't make any sense; you can't *dynamically* create member variables.  What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you please explain what you trying to achieve with that? Like sample pseudo-code how you plan to use that magical "new public variable"?

Comment: It seems like you need an array

Comment: Such things are possible in many languages; I do not think you can do that with C# just as easily as you can in, say, Javascript.

Comment: Technically you could use a Dynamic object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) but they are slow and there's most likely a much better way to solve your problem.

Comment: Wild guess: "Inspector" == "Watch" window when debugging.

Comment: The side bar that lets you change variables, like the name and such. Like in Visual Studios. The propertes window.

Comment: "The better way to solve your problem" is something we can only help you with once you explain better what your problem actually is. Write down **in words** what it is you actually want to do, then write the code to do that. If it still doesn't work, show us the part which isn't working, and hopefully you'll be able to explain it better.

Comment: Another wild guess: OP wants to dynamically add properties to the Visual Studio properties window at _design time_ based on the value of another property. Perhaps OP is creating a custom control.

Comment: @Aaahh, to answer effectively we need to first understand your question.

Comment: @Aaahh I don't see anyone making fun of you. I see people asking for specific details and then trying to guess what you meant when the details didn't clear up the problem (as, ultimately, I did). If you feel you've been wronged by someone, flag their post for moderator attention.

Comment: Use dynamic  Toggle= new ExpandoObject();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, that code is supposed to produce a class that looks like this after 5 updates

```
public bool Toggle;
public bool Toggle0;
public bool Toggle1;
public bool Toggle2;
public bool Toggle3;
public bool Toggle4;

// test Toggle3

if (Toggle3)
   // DoSomething
```

If so, you really want an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So your code would become

```
public List<bool> Toggles = new List<bool>();
public void Update(bool newValue)
{
   Toggles.Add(newValue);
}
```

You would access it by:

```
if (Toggles[3])
    // do something
```

In the watch window, this will show up as a list of booleans. You can change individual values easily.

Comment: Thank you, this is alot closer to what I want.